# Scheduling jobs on windows

Tags: windows, backup, jobs, schedule

What is the best way of scheduling simple batch jobs on windows?  My current need is to dump some SVN repositories each night and FTP the dumps to our external FTP side and then e-mail one or more people that the backup has completed/failed.

This sounds like the sort of thing I would usually do in a unix script + cron.  Is that possible on windows?  Perhaps using Cygwin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Scheduled Tasks. This area is available through the control panel and may require administrative rights. It's basically crontab for Windows. Run a Windows batch file (or any executable) at a specified interval using a specified user.

Comment: You can also use the command-line tool, schtasks.exe, to schedule tasks.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(VS.85).aspx .    This is just a different interface into the same task scheduler subsystem accessible via the control panel applet.